# How to execute multiple post action in jenkins declarative pipeline on different nodes?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have the below scenario where I have to clean up work from the stages executed like delete files under different nodes as a clean step. I tried the below but getting the error "Error when executing always post condition:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'agent' found among steps"

```
pipeline {
stages {...}
post {
    always{
     node 'test1'{
      steps{...}
      }
     }
    cleanup{
     node 'test2'{
      steps{...}
     }
    }
    success {...}
    failure {...}
 }
}
```

Don't want it to be dependent on a stage like this.

```
stage('Clean up'){
   agent {node 'test1'}
    steps{
           sh '''
           #!/bin/bash
               echo "Cleaning up"
          '''
     }
     post {
      always {
       sh '''
           #!/bin/bash
             rm test/*
          '''
      }
    }
  }
```

Want it to run to clean up regardless any stage fails.

Comment: Try `script{ node 'test1' { ... }}`

Answer (score 0):

For those who will search in the future.

```
post { 
   always { 
      node('test1') { 
         script {
            ...
         }
      } 
   }
}
```